# Pseudo-Theorem on parallel lines in a quadrilateral - Proof & Reference Request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Yesterday I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853253/parallel-lines-in-2-simplex) concerning an argumentation, and keep on thinking about the problem I realized that what I was missing is probably a basic result in linear algebra. Actually I am not sure this is a theorem or not (probably it is), but it should be as follow.

**Pseudo theorem in $\Re^2$:**
Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d}$ four vectors in $\Re^2$ such that it is not possible that three of them lie on the same line. Construct a quadrilateral with the four vectors as vertices. Then, if the difference between two adjacent vertices (say $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$) is equal to the difference of the opposite vertices (say $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{d}$), the line upon which $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ lie is parallel to the line upon which $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{d}$ lie.

Now, I never found anything like this anywhere (I am self-taught), and I do not really know how to come up with the proof, if it exists. Moreover I am wondering if - assuming it is true in $\Re^2$ - the result can be extended in higher dimensions.

Any feedback concerning references or a proof is more than welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous. There are several things which I could interpret as *"the difference between two adjacent vertices (say $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$) is equal to the difference of the opposite vertices (say $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{d}$)"*.

One interpretation would be that side $AB$ has the same *length* as side $CD$. This condition is not sufficient for $AC$ to be parallel to $CD$. You can draw any two arbitrary line segments of the same length, oriented however you want, and still construct a quadrilateral. I'm sure it will not be difficult for you to construct a counter-example with pen and paper.

A second interpretation would be that the *vector* $\mathbf{b-a}$ is equal to the *vector* $\mathbf{d-c}$. Then indeed, the two sides are parallel and of the same length. This is a trivial equality because the direction vector of the lines $AB$ and $CD$ are determined by $\mathbf{b-a}$ and $\mathbf{d-c}$ respectively, and these two vectors are equal. This condition is also strong enough to ensure that the other pair of opposite sides are also parallel.

A third interpretation, related and stronger than the first, would be to require *both* pairs of opposite sides to be equal in length. Let us name our quadrilateral $ABCD$ with vertices labelled in clockwise order. Then we require, $|AB|=|CD|$ *and* $|BC|=|DA|$. In this case, the quadrilateral (assuming it is non-self intersecting) is in fact a parallelogram. This is an elementary result which you can find in any book on Euclidean geometry. For completeness, I will reproduce a proof here.

**Proof:** Consider the diagonal $AC$. Triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDA$ have all three sides equal since by assumption $|AB|=|CD|$ and $|BC|=|DA|$. This means that the two triangles are congruent. Repeating the argument with the other diagonal, this proves that the two pairs of opposite angles are congruent:
$$\alpha = \angle ABC = \angle CDA,\ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \beta = \angle BCD = \angle DAB$$
Notice that since internal sums of quadrilaterals always sum to $360^\circ$, we must have
$$\alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$$
But this is precisely the condition needed for the opposite sides to be parallel. $\square$

As for the generalization into higher dimensions, you will have to clearly state what exactly you wish to generalize.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the completeness of your answer. Actually I realized I was referring to the second interpretation. What I was missing (and still I am probably) is the "trivial equality" concerning the direction vectors.

Comment: @Kolmin The point about equality of vectors is more of a definition than a theorem. Any line $\ell$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ may be written in the form $\ell(t) = \mathbf{v}t + \mathbf{u},$ where $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is a parameter. This is exactly the same as the slope-intercept form for lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $\mathbf{v}$ defines the direction of the line (hence the term direction vector). If the vectors $\mathbf{b-a}$ and $\mathbf{d-c}$ are equal, then the lines they define have equal directions. This is precisely what it means to be parallel. Does that clear things up a bit?

Comment: Definitely. Again, thanks a lot!